# How can I apply a horizontal scroll bar on the x axis for my table?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I noticed there are some different ways to do this and some differences with the IE8 browser. I have a `<table>` that contains a table. The table might have a width of 500px or 1500px depending on the columns.

How can I make it so that when the table width is bigger than the div outer container that a scrollbar appears along the bottom. Also do I need to enclose this table in a DIV to make it work?

```
<table id="dataTable">
 xxx
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-x) property:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
   <table id="dataTable">
     ...
   </table>
</div>
```

```
#wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work directly on the table for me, needs a surrounding container.

Comment: @Mash yes, it needs a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/TjH2B/)**

```
<div id="div1" class="div-scroll">
<table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
        <td > col1 </td>
        <td > col2</td>
        <td > col3</td>
    </tr>    
</table>    
</div>​
```

Comment: Hey @adil, I think the fiddle goes to somewhere else.

Comment: Glad to hear friend from you :)

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
table {
    width: 200px;
}
div {
    width: 100px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pXx7K/1/

​